# Drawing Bitmap on to screen using CRenderTarget::DrawBitmap and Byte Array (instead of file) in VC++

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mfc

I am working with COSMCtrl in order to display maps on to the viewing window.

In the COSMCtrl, a file name is passed on to the CD2DBitmap constructor along with CRenderTarget object. But my application doesnt have image file. It will receive image data (in the form of byte array) from  a database.

Could any one please help me in finding out the solution ?

The sample code is below:

```
    BOOL COSMCtrl::DrawTile(CRenderTarget* pRenderTarget, const CD2DRectF& rTile, int nTileX, int nTileY)
{
  //What will be the return value from this function (assume the worst)
  BOOL bSuccess = FALSE;

  //Form the path to the cache file which we want to draw
  int nZoom = static_cast<int>(m_fZoom);
  CString sFile(GetTileCachePath(m_sCacheDirectory, nZoom, nTileX, nTileY, FALSE));

  //Get the fractional value of the zoom
  double fInt = 0;
  double fFractionalZoom = modf(m_fZoom, &fInt);

  //Try to obtain the standard tile
  CD2DBitmap bitmap(pRenderTarget, sFile);

// I have a Byte Array. I should pass the byte array instead of file

  //Determine how the tile should be draw
  BOOL bStandardTile = FALSE;
  if (fFractionalZoom == 0 && SUCCEEDED(bitmap.Create(pRenderTarget)))
   bStandardTile = TRUE;

  //Load up the image from disk and display it if we can
  if (bStandardTile)
  {
    //Draw the image to the screen at the specified position
    pRenderTarget->DrawBitmap(&bitmap, rTile, 1.0);
    bSuccess = TRUE;
  }

return bSuccess;
}
```

1. I am not allowed to save the byte array to disk (as image).
2. I have tried using the other constructor of CD2DBitmap which accepts CRenderTarget and HBITMAP. but of no use

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand that correctly. What exactly do you expect from the code above and what is happening instead?

Comment: I have the above code which reads from a file and renders on to the screen. Instead of file, i need to render the bitmap on to the screen with the image data (byte array) obtained from internet

Comment: And what specifically goes wrong? You write "I am not allowed to save the byte array to disk". What happens if you try? Do you get an exception or does your application crash? Where? Then: "I have tried [...] but of no use". What went wrong there?

Comment: Its not about the exception. The requirement itself was such that nothing should be written on to the disk

Comment: If you know how to write to a file, but fail to implement any other scheme, simply use a [CMemFile](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tzdxd4x0.aspx), and move on. As always, if you aim to ever become proficient in MFC you **absolutely must** learn the Windows API first. This is mandatory, no shortcuts available.

Comment: I have tried CMemFile as well. But the code block "CD2DBitmap bitmap(pRenderTarget, sFile);" accepts the file name as one of the parameter. And i found no means to use CMemFile

Comment: Then now would be a good time to wrap your head around the Windows API, and create a `HBITMAP` from an in-memory array. [CreateBitmap](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd183485.aspx) is a good place to start.